# Always force limitstart=0 for component's paginated lists when revisiting the list

Tags: component, administrator, pagination

I am facing problem with Joomla listing.

When I log-in into Joomla admin panel and use pagination for listing, if I click and visit the 3rd page of the paginated data of the 3rd page, then go to another page and later return at the same page listing which I was earlier - Joomla pagination will start from 3rd page.

I need to set `limitstart` value 0 whenever user come to the listing.

So each time I visit the page, pagination should  start from 0 not according to last viewed page - I need to display first page data each time when user visit the list page.

Answer (score -1):

May be this post will fix your issue of start limit of pagination in joomla.

[Pagination confusion - Pagination uses start, PopulateState uses limitstart?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/867/pagination-confusion-pagination-uses-start-populatestate-uses-limitstart)

Hope this will help you.